# HttpSendRequestA stops function execution

Tags: c++, wininet

I have following code

```
HINTERNET hInternet = InternetOpenA("InetURL/1.0", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
HINTERNET hConnection = InternetConnectA(hInternet, "api.github.com", 80, " ", " ", INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 0);
HINTERNET hData;
s_Request = "/repos/MyApp/releases/latest"

hData = HttpOpenRequestA(hConnection, "GET", s_Request.c_str(), NULL, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_FLAG_KEEP_CONNECTION, 0);
HttpAddRequestHeaders(hData, _T("accept: application/json"), -1, HTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_ADD);

bool bSend = HttpSendRequestA(hData, NULL, 0, NULL, 0);
```

The problem is - at the moment Github servers are down and my program hangs indefinately at HttpSendRequestA line.
Is there any way I can prevent these cases? For instance - if server doesn't respond, skip this particular SendRequest and move to other functions? I don't understand how to "catch" this case because application code halts completely and I see no way to detect it.

Comment: Does `InternetSetOption`+`INTERNET_OPTION_CONNECT_TIMEOUT` work?

Comment: I added these 2 lines after InternetOpenA function(first line).
 DWORD dwTimeout = 600;
 InternetSetOption(hInternet, INTERNET_OPTION_RECEIVE_TIMEOUT, &dwTimeout, sizeof(DWORD));

However Github servers just went up and everything works as expected.
Is there any way to reproduce the issue? Giving invalid server name doesn't work - HttpSendRequestA doesn't get stuck.